# Angular:Hide show child component from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on angular 5. I have 2 components, COMP1(this has a buttonA) and COMP2(this has a buttonB).
When I load COMP1, COMP2 should be hidden.
As sson as I click on a buttonA on COMP1, COMP2 should be visible and when I click on buttonB on COMP2, the COMP2 should hide.

How to achieve this?

COMP1 is:

```
<COMP2></COMP2>
<button>buttonA</button>
```

COMP2 is:

```
<button>buttonB</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your comp1 component have a boolean which keeps track whether or not the button b should be shown:

```
export class Comp1Component {
  showComp2: boolean = false;
}
```

Inside your comp2 component have an output which emits when clicked on the button:

```
export class Comp2Component {
  @Output() buttonClick = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

Then change your template of comp1 to this:

```
<COMP2 *ngIf="showComp2" (buttonClick)="showComp2 = false"></COMP2>
<button (click)="showComp2 = true">buttonA</button>
```

Change your template of comp2 to:

```
<button (click)="buttonClick.emit()">buttonB</button>
```

Comment: Onclick of button from Comp1, the value of 'showComp2' is setting to 'true' but Comp2 is not visible on the screen. Any leads to this?

Comment: There can only be a typo somewhere. Can you edit your question to include the entirety of both components

Comment: Yes sir, it was a typo. I am now able yo see the Comp2, but on click of button on Comp2, Comp2 is not hiding. Please help

Comment: Going to need to see the entire components :)

Comment: Done. I had to restart the serve and it working now. Thanks

Comment: @Anna alright, the cli can be annoying sometimes with their caching indeed. Glad I could help

Comment: Perfect answer. I was looking for exactly this functionality. Thanks @PierreDuc